# When android FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates needs to check permission?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing project where I need to have location updates,when I called requestLocationUpdates method it required checking permission so I implemented it in this way:

```
 private void startLocationUpdates(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, MapsActivity.this);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

}
```

but I have seen in google's sample code that they hadn't checked permission and no error or warning appeared.

```
 protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

It's targetSdkVersion was 22 and I corrected it to 23;but it still doesn't requires permission.
my question is when LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates method requests permission?
P.S googles full sample code: [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)

**edit**:
my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gio.autostop"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm testing on android version 6.0.1, on model Nexus 5

Comment: When you uninstall/reinstall your app, it doesn't show the permission request?  You can also manually revoke the permission to test....

Comment: Yes,it's showing permission request when I reinstall my app, but my question is why my requestLocationUpdates method needs permission,when in google's sample code there is no permission request for locationupdates and it works well without any error or warning.

Comment: If you uninstall/reinstall and use the google sample code on Android 6, it should crash with a security exception.

Comment: Yes, it's true.error:Call requires permissions that may be rejected by user.
why google's sample code doesn't need permission and my code does?

Comment: Target api-22 in the sample

Comment: I altered it to 23,but it still doesn't ask any permission.

Comment: it will not ask you any for permissions. Rather you have to ask user. Otherwise app will crash on Marshmallow